# Can't get my code to divide with decimal precision

Tags: c++

I'm trying to write a prime number indentify-er, but every time I try to divide the inputted number, it won't go to the decimals. I've tried using a double variable and float variable. I'm a beginner, so I might have to ask a few questions about your answer. Here is the code (looper is the number I used for the while function to keep it going).

```cpp
#include <iostream>

int main() {

    int input = 0;
    float result = 0;
    int looper = 2;

    std::cout << "Please enter your number.\n";
    std::cin >> input;

    if (input == 1 or input == 0) {
        std::cout << "Your number is neither.\n";
    }

    while (looper < 1000002) {
        result = input / looper;
        std::cout << input / looper;
        if (fmod(result, 1) == 0) {
            std::cout << "Your number is composite.\n";
            std::cout << result;
            looper = 1000003;
        }
        else if (fmod(result, 1) != 0) {
            std::cout << "Your number is prime.\n";
        }

        looper = looper + 1;

    }
}
```

Comment: An integer dvided by an integer returns integer, even if you assign that to a float. Convert one of the integer to a float first and then division will return a float.

Comment: Both input and looper are `ints`, not `doubles` or `floats.` When you do the division, the resulting return value for `std::cout << (int)` will be truncated to an `int.` Your `result` logic looks proper, just not the `std::cout`

Comment: Integer math results in integer values, and integers don't have decimal points. You should read your notes or book to review the data types section.

Comment: Also be aware that once you start dealimg in floats you run into all sorts of interesting issues with arithmetic https://floating-point-gui.de/

Answer (score 0):

There are some rules for arithmetic calculations.

- if any of the operands is `float` or `double`, then the result is truncated to the `float` or `double` type respectively (int < float and int < double cause the size of int, float, double are 4, 8, 8 bytes respectively, but the sizes may be different depending on os & compiler.
- if any of the operands is `long` type, then the result is truncated to the `long` type (int < long cause the size of int long types are 4, 8 bytes respectively, but the sizes may be different depending on os & compiler.)

However, you can do better alternative ( use moduler operator `%`) here like following:

```cpp
if (input % looper == 0) {
    // case for composit
    // in other words input value is completely divisible by current value of looper
}
else {
    // input value is not completely divisible by current value of looper
    // this means there is a remainder exists
}
```

Though you have put the `printf` statement for **prime** number at wrong place, your provided algorithm is can be improved to determine whether an integer number is prime or not.

Comment: Updated the ans